# Syntax for if statement in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, grep

```
for i in $( find . -name 'x.txt' ); do; if [ grep 'vvvv' ]; 
then; grep 'vvvv' -A 2 $i | grep -v vvvv | grep -v '-' >> y.csv; else 
grep 0 $i >> y.csv; fi; done
```

What might be wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't iterate over `find`'s output that way -- see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Your immediate error, though, is one that http://shellcheck.net/ will identify automatically.

Comment: (Also, `[ grep vvvv ]` is certainly not going to do what you want/expect it to; note that `[` is an alternate name for the command named `test`, not part of the syntax for `if`).

Answer (score 2):

A `;` is not permitted after `do`.

This is automatically detected by http://shellcheck.net/

---

That said, what you probably want is something more like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
  if grep -q -e vvvv -- "$i"; then
    grep -e 'vvvv' -A 2 -- "$i" | egrep -v -e '(vvvv|-)'
  else
    grep 0 -- "$i"
  fi
done < <(find . -name 'x.txt' -print0) >y.csv
```

Note:

- Using `find -print0` and `IFS= read -r -d ''` ensures that all possible filenames (including filenames containing spaces, newlines, etc) can be handled correctly. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more background on this idiom.
- `if grep ...` should be used if you want `if` to check the output of `grep`. Making it `if [ grep ... ]` means you're passing `grep` as an argument to the `test` command, not running it as a command itself.
- We open `y.csv` **only once** for the entire loop, rather than re-opening the file over and over, only to write a single line (or short number of lines) and close it.
- The argument `--` should be used to separate options from positional arguments if you don't control those positional arguments.
- When `-` is passed to `grep` as a string to search for, it should be preceded by `-e`. That said, in the present case, we can combine both `grep -v` invocations and avoid the need altogether.
- Expansions should *always* be quoted. That is, `"$i"`, not `$i`. Otherwise, the values are split on whitespace, and each piece generated is individually evaluated as a glob, preventing correct handling of filenames modified by either of these operations.